# What is the list all elements of $\Lambda^2(F_2^3)$ and its addition table.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, exterior-algebra

> Exterior product:  Let $V$ be a vector space over $F_2$. Define $Sym^2(V)$ as the fixed of $σ$ and $ \Lambda^2(V)= V \otimes V/Sym^2(V) $. List all elements of $\Lambda^2(F_2^3)$ and write its addition table.

Here is what I got so far so I wrote it down but I don't know how to continue. Could anyone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $e_1  = (1,0,0), e_2 = (0,1,0), e_3 = (0,0,1)$.

You already noted that the vectors $e_i \otimes e_j$ form a basis of $V \otimes V$.  It follows that the vectors $e_i \otimes e_j + Sym^2(V)$ form a spanning set of the quotient space $(V \otimes V)/ Sym^2(V)$.  It follows that any *maixmal linearly independent subset* of those vectors will be a basis for our quotient space.

Now, consider the vectors
$$
e_1 \otimes e_2 + Sym^2(V), \quad e_1 \otimes e_3 + Sym^2(V), \quad 
e_2 \otimes e_3 + Sym^2(V), \quad 
$$
Why do these vectors form a *maximal linearly independent set*?  That is, why does adding any vector $e_i \otimes e_j + Sym^2(V)$ make our set linearly dependent?  Once you answer that, you can know with certainty (by the "dimension theorem" of linear algebra) that this set is a basis.

I'll leave it to you to work through the addition table.